# Guidelines for opening and saving files

Tags: .net

I am writing a basic windows program and I am looking for some basic guidelines for handling opening and saving files. {windows}
**Do you have any resources or do you want to give some pointers?**

Some of my questions{vb.net if it matters}:

-Where do the saved files go? Under My Documents? Appdata?

-How do I get the path to those locations? I can't hardcode it.

-Using the dialogs in VS, does the dialog remember the last location navigated to, or does it always open to the location set as the default?

-How do I restrict the dialog to only show files of a specific file type? (like *.exp ?)

Comment: This is *way* too broad. Some of your questions are good, but they've been asked and answered already. The rest really should be posted as separate questions, with more context on what programming languages/environments/technologies/etc. you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Where do the saved files go? Under My Documents? Appdata?**

First thing to ask is what versions of windows will you be supporting? Different versions have different conventions / best practices and/or limitations. For example If you want to target Windows Vista or latter you should try to avoid using a location accessible only by an administrator. See [Special Folders and Custom Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for a list of folders and a brief description. My interpretation is this:

- If you are saving application data that is the user won't have the ability to select the location then the Users Application Data folder would be appropiate.
- If you are saving documents or other items that the user might want to move or manage outside your program (images, saved games etc...) then you should default it to My Documents, but it would be nice for the user to configure a default location if they wish to change it.

**2. How do I get the path to those locations? I can't hardcode it**

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) page

Comment: +1, but I think one should have avoided locations accessible by only privilege users on NT/2000/XP too.

Comment: I agree Kenny, I was thinking about UAC guidelines but yes you should always try and hit the lowest privalges possible.

Comment: Thank you @JoshBerke, a great answer to a lousy question. That MSDN link was gold.

Comment: @F Oak: Thanks...hope it helps